# Why does Yosef use intermediaries to ask Paro for permission to bury Yaakov, when until now he addressed Paro directly?

Tags: malchut-royalty, yosef, vayechi

[Bereishit 50:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8245#v=4), after Yaakov's death and mourning, says that Yosef spoke to Paro's house (בֵּית פַּרְעֹה) and asked them to ask Paro for leave so he could go bury his father.  During the famine and when Yaakov comes to Mitzrayim we see Yosef address Paro directly, as one would expect from someone in his position.

Why the change here?  Perhaps the indirect request is because of something about this specific case (leaving Mitzrayim to bury his father)?  Or perhaps, after the famine and the arrival of his family, Yosef didn't have as elevated a position so he needed to go through intermediaries now?  Why doesn't he ask Paro directly?

Rashi is silent on this.  Someone I study with speculated that after Yosef brought shepherds (who are [taboo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12741/472)) to Mitzrayim maybe his relationship with Paro suffered, but he doesn't have a source.

Comment: scroll down http://www.chabad.org/parshah/in-depth/plainBody_cdo/AID/2710 to 50:6. The talmud [Sotah 36b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=36b&format=pdf) says that pharaoh refused to let yosef bury yaakov until yosef threatened to break an oath he made to pharaoh, never to reveal pharaoh's lack of knowledge of hebrew. It is possible that this is why Yosef initiated the conversation publicly, so that pharaoh couldn't just brush him off.

Answer (score 13):

[*S'forno*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obadiah_ben_Jacob_Sforno) [says](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=1&perek=50&mefaresh=sforno) it would be inappropriate for *Yosef* to approach the king while dressed in mourning.

Similarly, [*Haamek Davar* says](http://www.sefaria.org/Haamek_Davar_on_Genesis.50.4) it would be inappropriate for *Yosef* to approach the king while before *Yaakov*'s burial, while he (*Yosef*) is an [*onen*](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281552/).

Comment: Thanks. He was dressed in mourning after sh'loshim?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, the _S'forno_ doesn't elaborate. To be honest, though, "mourning" is my loose translation/interpretation. He says "sackcloth".

Comment: @MonicaCellio As he still hadn't buried Yaakov, and there was more mourning yet to come( see especially [v. 10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8245#v=10)), he could have still been "dressed in mourning".

Answer (score 11):

The sefer [באר יוסף](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47091&st=&pgnum=178)  (a sefer I very highly recommend) writes that immediately after Yaakov died the enslavement of Yisrael to Egypt began. This even affected Yosef's elevated status, so much so that he could no longer appeal to Pharaoh directly concerning Yaakov's burial, and instead had to appeal to the members of his household to intercede for him.

Answer (score 4):

*Tora Sh'lema* cites *Tz'ror Hamor* as citing a *midrash* as offering two explanations:

1. *Yosef* didn't want to leave his father's side (out of respect for him), so sent messengers instead.
2. (If I understand it correctly:) *Yosef* was worried that if he approach *Par'o* with the request himself then *Par'o*'s people may dissuade *Par'o* from granting the request. So he got them formally on his side. (I'll include the language of the *Tora Sh'lema* in case I'm misunderstanding it: "כדי שישאוהו עצה שיניחוהו לעלות שהיה מתיירא מהם שלא יעצוהו שלא לעלות. מתלא אמר קיימון לקטיגורא כי היכא דלא ליטרדך.‏‎")

Answer (score 2):

Many commentaries address this question. A few explain that Yosef couldn't make a request for himself, either because he was embarrassed or because it was against the protocol, or that the request required special convincing of Pharaoh:

- **Radak**

> אל זקני ביתו כי הוא בוש לדבר לו על דברי עצמו

- **R. Avraham Ben HaRambam**

> גדולי ביתו ומכובדיו ומנימוסי המלכים שהמבקש מהם אפילו המכובד שבמכובדים על צרכיו הפרטיים לא יבקש אלא על ידי (אמצעות של) שר משרת המלך

- **Ralbag**

> ואז דיבר יוסף אל בית פרעה שישתדלו עם פרעה שיתן לו רשות ללכת לקבור את אביו כאשר השביעהו

- **R. Samson Raphael Hirsch**

> תמוה הדבר שיוסף למרות מעמדו הרם הגיש את בקשתו בדרך בלתי־ישירה נראה שיוסף לא היה בטוח שבקשתו תתקבל ולכן רצה לפנות בעקיפין קל יותר לשני הצדדים להתעלם מסירוב שניתן ונתקבל באמצעות צד שלישי
> הדבר היה קשור כנראה לאיבה שרחשו המצרים כלפי זרים לא מצא חן בעיני המצרים שאיש נכרי על אחת כמה וכמה שהוא מכנען עמד בראש המדינה קבורת יעקב הזכירה לעם את מקום מוצאו של יוסף

However, most of the commentaries explain that something about Yosef's state of mourning/recent death of his father made it inappropriate or illegal to appear before Pharaoh:

- **Bereishit Rabbah**

> ולמה לא נכנס הוא ר' יהושע דסכנין בשם ר' שמואל שאין אבל נכנס בפלטין של מלך

- **Midrash Sechel Tov**

> מה לאמר אלא כך אמר להם אתם ראויין לומר לו שאין אני ראוי לבוא לפלטין של מלך בבגדי אבל וכה"א כי אין לבא אל שער המלך בלבוש שק

- **R. Avraham Ben HaRambam**

> ואבי אבא ז"ל נתן טעם לזה לפי שהוא כלומר יוסף היה אבל ואין ראוי מצד נימוס המלכים ליכנס לפניהם בבגדי אבילות

- **Paneach Raza**

> וקשה למה לא דיבר בעצמו וי"ל בעבור בגדי אבלות שהי' לבוש ואין לבא אל המלך בלבוש שק

- **Tur**

> והוא לא דבר כי לא בא אל שער המלך בבגדי אבל שהיה לבוש

- **Seporno**

> כי אין לבוא אל שער המלך בלבוש שק

- **Shadal**

> ולא דבר לפרעה עצמו כי אין לבוא אל שער המלך בלבוש שק ואבל (ראזנמילר) וכן במדרש  אמרו שאין אבל נכנס בפלטין של מלך ואעפ"י שכבר עברו שלשים ימי הבכי הנה יוסף שעדיין היה עתיד לעלות לקבור את אביו יתכן שהיה עדיין לבוש לבושי אבל

- **Netziv**

> כי כל זמן שלא נקבר אביו הרי הוא בכלל אונן ואינו ראוי להתראות את המלך

- **Meshech Chachmah**

> לשיטת רמב"ן אונן כ"ז שלא נקבר אסור לסוך ולרחוץ ולקשט וגם לרמב"ם דאונן שרי אין זה מדרך הנימוס וכבוד אביו לסוך וללבוש בגדי שררות כפי הראוי להיות בבואו אל המלך בעוד אביו מת מוטל לפניו לכן לא היה יכול לכנס אל פרעה לדבר עמו

Comment: I'll +1 this for your research if you translate all of these sources.